# Probability distribution of a random components vector

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions

The vector $\rho$ has components: $(\rho_x,\rho_y,\rho_z)$ in a three - dimensional cartesian reference frame, where: 
$$\rho_x=a+\nu_x,\rho_y=b+\nu_y,\rho_z=c+\nu_z$$
with: $a,b,c$ constants and $\nu_x,\nu_y,\nu_z$
random variables with gaussian distribution: $N(0,\sigma)$.

My question is: what is the joint probability to find:
$$\theta_0\le\theta\le\theta_1$$
together to
$$\phi_0\le\phi\le\phi_1?$$
($\phi$ and $\theta$ are the angles of the vector in a polar spherical reference frame.$\phi_0,\phi_1,\theta_0,\theta_1$ are obviously constants).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you assuming $\rho_x, \rho_y, \rho_z$ are independent?

Comment: @gt6989b: yes. They are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry and random structure of the problem is the same as that after
applying the transfomration $\left( X, Y, Z \right) = \frac{1}{\sigma} \left(
\nu_x, \nu_y, \nu_z \right)$ so let us look at the distribution of that vector
which a product of three standard normally distributed variables.

Upon applying the spherical coordinate transformation and upon computing the
[jacobion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Examples) of the transformation $\left( r^2 \sin \theta \right)$, we get the
joint density of spherical coordinates $\left( r, \theta, \varphi \right)$ for
$r > 0$, $\theta \in \left[ 0,  \pi \right)$ and $\varphi \in \left[ 0, 2\pi
\right)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f_{r, \theta, \varphi} \left( r, \theta, \varphi \right) & = & f_{X, Y, Z}
  \left( r \sin \theta \cos \varphi, r \sin \theta \sin \varphi, r \cos \theta
  \right) r^2 \sin \theta\\
  & = & \left( 2 \pi \right)^{- \frac{3}{2}} \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2}
  \left\{ r^2 \left( \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \varphi + \sin^2 \theta \sin^2
  \varphi + \cos^2 \theta \right) \right\} \right) r^2 \sin \theta\\
  & = & \sin \theta \times \frac{1}{2 \pi} \times \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} r^2
  \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2} r^2 \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $\varphi$ is uniform and $\theta$ has obvious density from the formula.

Please check if I did not make any computational mistakes.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't answer to the question about the joint probability to have the two angles in the interval defined by the constrains.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra Yes it does.